# Websockets in a Firefox web extension background page

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to port a Chrome extension to Firefox that uses web sockets (Socket.io) in the background page. It works fine in Chrome but in FF doesn't seem to work.

I found that some people have used PageWorkers but that appears to be for older FF Add-ons.

Does anyone know how to get web sockets to function properly in FF web extensions, specifically in the background pages?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It works fine in Firefox background pages. My Node.js service wasn't running. Once I started it, it connected without an issue.

However, for some reason Firefox doesn't output Socket.io JS errors (connection refused) like Chrome does.